# I have some problems in 3 activity for pass int to another class and unlocked level

Tags: java, android, int, sharedpreferences, locked

I have **main.xml** and ***main.class*** that has two buttons named : **Level 1** and **Level 2**

each button has a function to open another class

```
level1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                   @Override
                  public void onClick(View v){
                       // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level1.class);
                       startActivity(i);              

    level2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

               @Override
              public void onClick(View v){
                   // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                   Intent i =new Intent(getApplicationContext(),level2.class);
                   startActivity(i);             
                    }             
              });
```

but the condition is **level 2 button** are locked but i dont know how to make a locked button, The first thing i want to ask is how to make a locked button

and to unlock **level 2 button**  , ***level1.class*** event must completed.
in ***level1.class*** has code like this

```
public class level1 extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

    int gamelifes=6, index=0, score=0;
    String [] answer ={"the answer"};

    lifes =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.lifestext);
    lifes.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    lifes.setText(String.valueOf(gamelifes));

    buttonanswer = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonanswer);
    buttonanswer.setOnClickListener(this);

    good =(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.youwin);
    good.setOnClickListener(this);

    buttonfinish = (Button)findViewById(R.id.finish);
    buttonfinish.setOnClickListener(this);

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub            

    edittext=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText); 
    if(v==buttonanswer) {

        String abc =edittext.getText().toString();              
        if(abc.equalsIgnoreCase(answer[index]))
        {
           good.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           buttonfinish.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
           score++;
        }
        else
        {
           gamelifes--;                     
        }

       buttonfinish.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

          public void onClick(View v){
             finish();          
          }
       });  
}
```

when the answer is right there will be show up some image and a button.
and `score++;` if the answer is correct and `gamelifes--;` if wrong.

my next question is how to make `score` and `gamelifes` values send to ***level2.class*** whereas the conditions when `buttonfinish` Click will `finish();` and return to ***Main.class*** and unlock the **level 2 button** in ***main.class***

then how to make a *sharedpreference* setting to save the unlock button?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, to make a button not clickable you can use:

```
level2.setEnabled(false);
```

Then, when it can be clicked you would just set it to true.

Secondly, `SharedPreferences` can be used to store your values, like score, which can then be accessed at any point in the application.

To set up `SharedPreferences`:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
preferences.edit().putInt("score", 100).apply();
```

Then to get the score later:

```
preferences.getInt("score");
```

So, if you wanted to use a saved boolean to know if the second level is unlocked you could do something like this:

```
SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("preferences", MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean levelTwoUnlocked = preferences.getBoolean("level2", false);

level2.setEnabled(levelTwoUnlocked);
```

Or if you want to set a buttons visibility:

```
if (levelTwoUnlocked) {
    level2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
} else {
    level2.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
```

Comment: If i re-open the game did the button still unlock or become lock again? There is no use  preference for the unlock button to save?

Comment: Use a preference Boolean. That way it stays looked or unlocked based on the saved Boolean value

Comment: Can you explain with some example code for that? I really dont know about how to use preference activity

Comment: @RoboticX - I have updated my answer with some additional code sample.

Comment: Oh okay bro i got it! but i have one question again, can i change ("level2", false); to gone or visible?